# How do I prevent $@ from clashing with double quote in bash?

Tags: shell, quoting

The following example returns "a b" instead of expected "a b c":

```
test() { bash -c "testargs() { echo \$@; }; testargs $@"; }
test "a b" c
```

It seems it's a quoting issue. How do I solve it without using "$*" instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$@` should pretty much only be used in the form `"$@"`, alone in a word. When `"stuff$@"` is expanded, that results in a list consisting of the first positional parameter with `stuff` prepended, then the other positional parameters. For example, if the positional parameters are `foo` and `bar`, you get two words: `stufffoo` and `bar`. That's one of your problems.

Another problem is that with `sh -c`, the first non-option argument becomes the script name which is available as `$0`. Subsequent non-option arguments become positional parameters. So `sh -c 'echo "$@"' foo bar qux` prints `bar qux` — `foo` is in `$0`, `bar` in `$1` and `qux` in`$2`.

To pass the arguments of the function to the script, use `$@` in the script (not, like you did, in the function — `"stuff$@"` is expanded in the shell that executes the function, due to the double quotes). And account for `$0`.

```
test() { bash -c 'testargs() { echo "$@"; }; testargs "$@"' myscript "$@"; }
```

Comment: If the first argument is wasted as $0, then why did it return "a b" instead of "c"?

Comment: @glarry In your code, `a b` is the first positional parameter in the function call, and it gets to be part of the argument to the `-c` option in the call to `bash`. `c` is the second positional parameter in the function call, and it's `$0` for the call to `bash -c …`. Your example is rather complex since it involves many successive expansions, I suggest to try simpler variations on it to get a feeling for how it works.

Answer (score 1):

$@ in double quotes expands to several words. `bash -c` accepts *string* as a parameter, but it can be followed by other *words* which are then assigned to positional parameters starting with $0.

You can therefore send the parameters to the code inside `bash -c` like this:

```
Test () { bash -c 'echo $@' -- "$@" ; }
Test "a b" c
```

This works for you case, too:

```
Test () { bash -c 'testargs() { echo $@ ; } ; testargs $@' -- "$@" ; }
Test "a b" c
```

If you want to keep the multiword parameters, add double quotes:

```
Test () {
    bash -c 'testargs() {
                 for a in "$@" ; do
                     echo "$a"
                 done
             }
             testargs "$@"' \
        -- "$@"
}
Test "a b" c
```

I used `Test`, as `test` already exists and might confuse readers.